# Is this a bug? "Method is never used." warning although it is used in setOnClickListener

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have been following https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/unit-2 tutorial on how to build Android apps in Android Studio. Code inspection is also introduced there as part of fixing warnings and making code perfect.

Adding my MainActivity.kt code:

```
package com.example.tiptime

import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import com.example.tiptime.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.text.NumberFormat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.tipResult.text = ""
        binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener {
            calculateTip()
        }

        // Hide keyboard on enter press
        binding.costOfServiceEditText.setOnKeyListener { view, keyCode, _ ->
            handleKeyEvent(
                view,
                keyCode
            )
        }
    }

    private fun calculateTip() {
        val cost = binding.costOfServiceEditText.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()
        if (cost == null) {
            binding.tipResult.text = ""
            return
        }

        val tipPercentage = when (binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
            R.id.option_twenty_percent -> 0.20
            R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> 0.18
            else -> 0.15
        }

        var tip = tipPercentage * cost
        if (binding.roundUpSwitch.isChecked) {
            tip = kotlin.math.ceil(tip)
        }
        val formattedTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
        binding.tipResult.text = getString(R.string.tip_amount, formattedTip)
    }

    private fun handleKeyEvent(view: View, keyCode: Int): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            // Hide the keyboard
            val inputMethodManager =
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I have completed part 2 of getting user input and I wanted to make sure there are no code warnings. But after using code inspection on project I noticed couple of warnings.
One warning is about calculateTip() and says: "Method is never used." although it is used in setOnClickListener.

After pressing button "Safe delete" it says: "function MainActivity.calculateTip() has 1 usage that is not safe to delete." that's completely opposite. Is this code inspection bug or I don't see some smart fix that is ment for this?

Attached screenshots also.

Method is never used:
[warning that shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzK4s.png)

Usages detected upon pressing safe delete:
[usages detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuxU8.png)

Comment: This bug is quite common, I have seen it on all IDEs that I have used. My only advice is to ignore it. IDE is just software and every software has bugs. Don't bother too much with those false warnings, you'll see a lot more of those soon when you work on bigger products

Answer (score 0):

I run the Google code and it seems ok on this, it uses the calculateTip() function.

Comment: Code is running fine. The question was about warning that shows up from IDE. Son Nguyen already replied that this is a common bug in other IDEs as well.

Comment: Inspecting the code, I can't see any warning about calculateTip() function never used.